# facing problem in loop while solving this code in java

Tags: java, c++

i am facing problem  using  while loop in java. I have seached a lot. but cant solve it. Specially using and operator , decrement operator.

Actually I want do the same code in java. But in java i can't use the while loop with these condition.

```
int dataSet;

scanf ("%d", &dataSet);

while ( dataSet-- ) {

    char a;
    int result = 0;

    while ( scanf ("%c", &a) && a != 'X' ) {

        result += function (a);
    }

    printf ("%d\n", result);
}
return 0;
```

Comment: what is wrong with it? include errors if you got some

Comment: Until when should the loop run ? At what value of dataSet should the loop stop ?

Comment: Actually I want  do the same code in java. But in java i  can't use the while loop with these condition.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dCbVsb7s87FJrLL9zs2u3ghEGA8cUorxNTi0oCgD600/edit?usp=sharing

here is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is [strong typed language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing). The condition will not be casted to boolean automatically how it doing, for example, javascript.

You can use `while ( dataSet-- > 0 )`

You should use only boolean values in conditions.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dCbVsb7s87FJrLL9zs2u3ghEGA8cUorxNTi0oCgD600/edit?usp=sharing


here is the problme..

Answer (score 0):

I am editing my answer.
Looks like your points to the ***inner while loop*** of your code.

New Edit:
You cannot achieve pure *scanf* functionality in Java. Read is either through Run Arguments, or through a File.

So you can put the expected characters in some file, then read those one by one. I'll share with you a similar snippted. Hopefully helps !

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("input.txt")); // to read file
    int dataSet = 10;
    while(dataSet-- >0) {
        String a=""; // using String here for storing letters
        int result = 0;
        while(!a.equals("X")) {
            a = sc.next();
            result += function(a);
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

---

Old Edit:
If only *while* condition is troubling  you

Try this '==' operator

Java does not understand 0 as *false*

```
while ( dataSet-- != 0 )
```

Comment: here is the problem......

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dCbVsb7s87FJrLL9zs2u3ghEGA8cUorxNTi0oCgD600/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

here is the code...

```
converter1 c1=new converter1();
  Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int data;
    data=s1.nextInt();
    while(data--  != 0){
        char a=0;
        int sum=0;
       do {
           a = s1.next().charAt(0);
           sum += c1.function(a);
       } while( a != 'X');
        System.out.println(sum);
```

but for the output  the input, it needs spaces between the characters 
like this ....( A B C X)...

without spaces like this....( ABCX ) it doesn't give the output.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid spaces in input, you can read read the whole input, and then further parse to fetch individual inputs

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputCollective = sc.next();
    char[] inputArray = inputCollective.toCharArray();
    for (char ch: inputArray) {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(ch+"");
        System.out.println(number);
    }
```

PS: code looks type of Fix! ..but it would be great if it helps :)